# Something wrong with GeoJSON for LineString

Tags: qgis, python, geojson, linestring

I'm using Python's GeoJSON package to created a simple LineString, put it in a Feature, and put that in a FeatureCollection I'll call `featColl`. `featColl.errors()` returns no errors. Below is the dumped GeoJSON file.  When I import it as a vector layer into QGIS, it opens without complaint.  but the layer is completely empty, and shows no line segments.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
     [
      [
       -122.271154,
       37.804348
      ],
      [
       -122.272057,
       37.80295
      ]
     ],
     [
      [
       -122.272057,
       37.80295
      ],
      [
       -122.278011,
       37.805288
      ]
     ],
    ]
   },
   "properties": {}
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you made some mistake when copying the GeoJSON into the question. QGIS gives "CRITICAL    Invalid Data Source : ...".

Comment: {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
     [
      [
       -122.271154,
       37.804348
      ],
      [
       -122.272057,
       37.80295
      ]
     ],
     [
      [
       -122.272057,
       37.80295
      ],
      [
       -122.278011,
       37.805288
      ]
     ]
    ]
   },
   "properties": null
  }
 ]
}

Comment: https://geojsonlint.com/ thinks it is invalid as well.

Comment: Apologies: cut&paste must have changed my sample somehow because i got different behavior from QGIS and geojsonlint?  in any case @user2856 made me aware of an extra set of brackets.   thanks al!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 levels of nesting in your coordinates which is not right for a simple linestring.

Either make it a `MultiLineString`

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection", 
  "features": [ 
    {
      "type": "Feature", 
      "geometry": { 
        "type": "MultiLineString", 
        "coordinates": [ 
          [ 
            [ -122.271154, 37.804348 ], 
            [ -122.272057, 37.80295 ] 
          ], 
          [ 
            [ -122.272057, 37.80295 ], 
            [ -122.278011, 37.805288 ] 
          ]  
        ] 
      }, 
      "properties": {} 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Or remove the extra level of nesting

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [-122.271154, 37.804348],
            [-122.272057, 37.80295],
            [-122.272057, 37.80295],
            [-122.278011, 37.805288]
          ]
        },
        "properties": {}
      }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @user2856!  now i'll check into how/where i got that extra set of brackets.